# Breadth first search recursion with php for a category

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

See the image hierarchy here

[image]

I am stuck with a problem, I want to add a user in MySQL table. Every level except root will consist of 5 users. If a top user is referred to it will check if its child sibling has 5 nodes and traverse down recursively.

I have done the code but the problem is if it calls it recursively it just checks down the first node and their subnodes, not checking their siblings. It's for user below level 2. I have managed root level and level 1:

```
function getSubChildVacancy($parent = 0) {
    $sql = "SELECT `uid`, `parent`, `level` FROM `users` WHERE 1 AND `parent` = $parent ORDER BY uid ASC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) >= BASE_USER_PER_LEVEL) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            $vacancy_array = getSubChildVacancy($row->uid);
            if (count($vacancy_array) > 0)
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $rows = fetchUser($parent);
        $vacancy_array = array("uid" => $rows->uid, "level" => $rows->level + 1);
    }

    return $vacancy_array;
}
```

Comment: What is your goal to achieve this? Recursion on a function with a query isn`t ok from my point of view. Do you want to insert users so that there is a balance or...?

Comment: yes i want to make a function to return the parent node whose child are emtyp or less than five. using breadth traversal mode

Comment: Why not selecting a count(uid) group by level then you would know how many users are on each level or group by parent then you would know each parent how many siblinhs he has...

Comment: Yes I did the same if root node has referred and that part is working fine but. The problem is when a node on 1st level referers it will be added under that node only not under its sibling 1st level nodes.
like ist level A, B, C, D,E
2nd level A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 .. B1, B2
like if NODE A referring then A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 will be checked and added under A1 like A1.1 
so i want to make a recursive function and cannot used level in this case.

Comment: any other way to do this?

Comment: Not sure i understood well : you want a Breadth-first tree traversal instead of your Depth-first tree traversal ? Little mistake i think : you asked for a tree with 5 users **per level**. Your image and example doesn't explain this, but 1 node having **5 subnodes**. I guess the second is true.